# How to bind TextArea using FieldGroup?

Tags: vaadin

How to bind TextArea using FieldGroup?
In project requirement, I need to bind TextArea with FieldGroup. Please, tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BeanItem<Person> item = new BeanItem<Person>(person);
fieldGroup.setItemDataSource(item)
fieldGroup.bind(textArea, "name");
```

The `propertyId` `"name"` is the name of the attribute you are binding to when you use a BeanItem. For example your bean is of class Person and you have `getName()`, `setName(..)`, then the `propertyId` is `"name"`.